# Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE

Tags: android, kotlin, continuous-integration, ktlint

When I run ktlint ci, the following unknown error occurs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHCIG.png)

I'm truly at a loss, would appreciate some help.

If any more information is needed let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

Comment: Error logs and code snippets should be added to question as text, not as screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your JDK version not compatible with your gradle

To check and replace your gradle verion go to
*File -> Project Structure -> Project*.

For JDK:
*File > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle*

You can choose correct pair here
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html